# Change JqueryAsset's jQuery version on certain page

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I have one asset bundle (AppAsset) which registered in my main layout (main.php) for common assets for the entire application:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/style.css',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

But on one certain page (not on entire app!) i need to change my jquery to a lower version and hook up other assets. And i'm registeting another asset bundle which depends on main asset bundle AppAsset in the desired view file :

```
class GalleryAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [ 
        'css/gamma/style.css',
        'css/gamma/noJS.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/gamma/modernizr.custom.70736.js',
        'js/gamma/jquery.masonry.min.js',
        'js/gamma/jquery.history.js',
        'js/gamma/js-url.min.js',
        'js/gamma/jquerypp.custom.js',
        'js/gamma/gamma.js',
    ];

    public $depends = [
        'app\assets\AppAsset',
    ];
}
```

The question is how can i change the Jquery's version in child asset bundle GalleryAsset or in one certain view file (page)?

Thank you and God bless helpers.

Answer (score 2):

You can read how to customize asset bundles in [offical documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles).

But customizing through application config is not suitable here, because at that moment requested route is unknown.

You can change the necessary asset bundle at runtime using [assetManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html) component:

```
use Yii;

...

Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['yii\web\JqueryAsset'] = [
    'sourcePath' => null,
    'js' => ['jquery.js' => 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js'],
];
```

Make sure to place this code before registering asset bundle related with that page.

In that case all assets depending on `yii\web\JqueryAsset` will cause registering older version.

Also I recommend additionally check compatibility of used plugins with this version (it's not that old though).

Comment: Thanks. I did as you sad:  `class JqueryAsset extends AssetBundle
{
 public $sourcePath = null;
 public $js = [
        'jquery.js'=>'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js',
    ];

}`    And now i have two jqueries on my page: first https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js and second yii\web\JqueryAsset's version which loading after all scripts and it breaks my code. Now how can i solve this problem?