# Yii2 - Change jQuery Version

Tags: yii2

I want to change the jQuery version of yii2. I've installed yii2 through composer. I've read a similar question here:
[Change JqueryAsset's jQuery version on certain page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340615/change-jqueryassets-jquery-version-on-certain-page)

But the problem I'm facing is where should I place this code? Should I place it on the view page? But I want to change the jquery version for all the pages. Is this code compatible for yii2?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can easily customize jquery asset bundle by configuring `assetManager` in the application components configuration (usually `config/web.php`), for example if you want to use a jquery file in `web/js` folder :

```
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                    'sourcePath' => null,
                    'basePath' => '@webroot',
                    'baseUrl' => '@web',
                    'js' => [
                        'js/jquery.js',
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles

Comment: In which file should I place this code? Can you pin point? Also, how should  I link to a `jquery.js` placed in my `web/js/` folder?